# Mongoid belongs_to not persisted when child calls create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Ruby noobie here.

When seeding my database, the association of `Haiku` -> belongs_to -> `User` is not persisting correctly via Mongoid. `Haiku` does not correctly store `user_id` in Mongo.

#### Doesn't work

```
#seeds.rb

1.upto(100) do
  user = User.create! name: 'foo'
  haiku = Haiku.create! content: 'hello world', user: user
  user.add_point({point_type: :tweet, value: 1, haiku: haiku})
end
```

#### Does Work

```
1.upto(100) do
  user = User.create! name: 'foo'
  haiku = Haiku.new content: 'hello world'
  haiku.user = user
  haiku.save!
  user.add_point({point_type: :tweet, value: 1, haiku: haiku})
end
```

After digging through the source, I can only assume `process_attributes` is not setting the relation correctly.

Why does it not work in the before section but does in the after secion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mass assignment is trying to set the user and that should work.

It's not working.

The reason is because `attr_accessible` is not called for the user reference. This macro needs to be for fields and references alike.

Answer (score 1):

Try this thru association

```
1.upto(100) do
  user = User.create! name: 'foo'
  haiku = user.haiku.create! content: 'hello world'
  user.add_point({point_type: :tweet, value: 1, haiku: haiku})
end
```

The above should work assuming your all your validation and callback has passed successfully

btw to ensure that your first section of your code works

ensure to do

> user.id.to_s

so the first section of code should look like this

```
1.upto(100) do
  user = User.create! name: 'foo'
  haiku = Haiku.create! content: 'hello world', user_id: user.id.to_s
  user.add_point({point_type: :tweet, value: 1, haiku: haiku})
end
```

**user.id.to_s** will give you the **bson hash** but user.id give you BSON object mongoid internally create a bson object for the hash supplied to it

Comment: I really didn't want my user to hold a collection to haikus, but your first example suggests I should. http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_many explicitly states relation is required on both sides. When I run your first example, it does work. Wanna try a couple more things before accepting.

Answer (score 0):

You should generally use rake tasks for publishing sample data to your database. Seeds are for *initial* data that your app *needs* to function.

However, I would do it like this:

```
1.upto(100) do
  user = User.create! name: 'foo'
  haiku = Haiku.create! content: 'hello world', user_id: user.id
  user.add_point({point_type: :tweet, value: 1, haiku: haiku})
end
```

Comment: Passing in user.id to the create function results in the same behavior as passing in the user instance which results in not persisting the relationship. I did remove the after_save callback which is cleaner. Thanks for the tip about seeds.rb, although I have found conflicting details on how to use it (ex: sample data population)